# Using regular expressions to match a time interval

Tags: php, regex

I'm having problems on how to preg_match this time statement.

```
TF 02:30 pm-04:00 am
```

I was able to separate the time into the array but I also want to get the `AM` and `PM` as well as the letter `T` and `F`.
This is for a class schedule module that I am working on. The data I got from the database is that string. I want to separate them so that I can manipulate the entries for the calendar that I have.

Here's what I have at this point.

```
$sampleString = 'T 02:30 pm-04:00 am';
$pattern = '/([0-1]?\d|2[0-9]):([0-5]?\d)/';
preg_match_all($pattern,$sampleString,$time);

print_r($time);
```

The output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
          [0] => 02:30 
          [1] => 04:00 ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
          [0] => 02 
          [1] => 04 ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
          [0] => 30 
          [1] => 00 ) 
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to get exactly? show us an example as you did also for the time

Comment: Firstly, you can't build a pattern based on only one example - you need to know what possible values each part of the string can hold. Break the string up into parts, and make a small regex for each one - for instance, you might match the first part with `/T?F?/`. Don't worry about capturing the right parts as you test - once you know how to match the whole string, you can go through the full regex working out which parts you need to capture, and wrap them in brackets.

Comment: the pattern for the string is: "[MTWHFSS] [0-1][0-2]:[0-5][0-9] [am|pm] - [0-1][0-2]:[0-5][0-9] [am|pm]". I want to get the day which is either "M" or "W", the hour, minute and whether it's am or pm.

Answer (score 1):

As recommended by IMSoP, splitting this up into parts makes it easier (looking again, I think your hour regex could use improvement, as it will accept hours from 0-29, I've changed it to `0?[1-9]|1[0-2]` instead, to accept only 1 - 12)

- Days: `[MTWHFS]+`
- Space: `\s`
- Hour: `0?[1-9]|1[0-2]`
- Colon: `:`
- Minute: `[0-5]?\d`
- Space: `\s`
- am/pm: `[ap]m`
- hyphen: `-`
- Hour: `0?[1-9]|1[0-2]`
- Colon: `:`
- Minute: `[0-5]?\d`
- Space: `\s`
- am/pm: `[ap]m`

Then just put them together, surrounding the desired capturing groups with parentheses:

```
([MTWHFS]+)\s(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5]?\d)\s([pa]m)-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5]?\d)\s([pa]m)
```